How high should water shutoff valves be?
This is what the cabinet under my kitchen sink looks like.

Obviously the S-trap and flexible tube need to be replaced with a proper P-trap and air admittance valve (the AAV would be appropriate because the vent stack pipe to which the drain is connected is about four feet away horizontally in the basement one floor down).
I also want to add proper quarter-turn shutoff valves to the water supply lines. You can see those in the background of the picture. The inflexible copper supply pipes go up about 20 inches (give or take a bit) above the floor of the cabinet, and the flexible supply hoses attach directly to the top of those copper pipes and then to the faucet.
So my question, then, is the following- Does any building-code/plumber's-rule-of-thumb/homeowner's-recommendation/practical-DIY-sense say anything about where those shutoff valves go other than "somewhere along the supply line before it gets to the sink"? Will the whole setup be fine if I put the valves on the very top of the copper pipes? Should I try to cut the pipes down and put the valves as close to the bottom of the cabinet as possible?

Do not know code, but I would like them to be easy to turn off without twisting my wrist around other pipes or hitting my knuckles on the floor/bottom.

You don't want them too close to the cabinet base, maybe up about 6 inches. You want to have a few extra inches in case you ever have to trim them shorter while replacing a shutoff valve in the future. Usually that's not necessary but it happens.

It's a real pain when the flex line from the faucet don't reach the shut off valves.
For that reason I usually place valves about 12 to 14 inches from the base of the cabinet.  I do try to be sure they will not be tucked too high and be difficult to get to behind the sink.
Remember these valves may be turned on and off once every few years, so aim for an easy connection to the faucet lines.  If I had your set up, I would put the valves near the end of the copper pipes.
